# Replace certain column with `filter(like = "")` in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, filter, dataframe

Sometimes, I would manipulate some columns of the dataframe and re-change it.

For example, one dataframe **df** has 6 columns like this:

> A, B1, B2, B3, C, D

And I want to change the values in the columns (B1,B2,B3) transform into (B1*A, B2*A, B3*A).
Aside the loop subroutine which is slow, the `df.filter(like = 'B')` will  accelerate a lot.

`df.filter(like = "B").mul(df.A, axis = 0)` can produce the right answer. **But I can't change the B-like columns** in `df` using:
 `df.filter(like = "B") =`df.filter(like = "B").mul(df.A. axis = 0)`

How to achieve it? I know using `pd.concat` to creat a new dataframe can get it done. But when the number of columns are huge, this method may be loss of  efficiency. What I want to do is to assign new value to the columns already exist.

Any advices would be appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('B')]
df[cols] = df[cols].mul(df.A, axis = 0)
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B1':[4,5,6],
                   'B2':[7,8,9],
                   'B3':[1,3,5],
                   'C':[5,3,6],
                   'D':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B1  B2  B3  C  D
0  1   4   7   1  5  7
1  2   5   8   3  3  4
2  3   6   9   5  6  3

cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('B')]
print (cols)
Index(['B1', 'B2', 'B3'], dtype='object')

df[cols] = df[cols].mul(df.A, axis = 0)

print (df)
   A  B1  B2  B3  C  D
0  1   4   7   1  5  7
1  2  10  16   6  3  4
2  3  18  27  15  6  3
```

**Timings**:

`len(df)=3`:

```
In [17]: %timeit (a(df))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.36 ms per loop

In [18]: %timeit (b(df1))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.39 ms per loop
```

`len(df)=30k`:

```
In [14]: %timeit (a(df))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.89 ms per loop

In [15]: %timeit (b(df1))
100 loops, best of 3: 4.71 ms per loop
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B1':[4,5,6],
                   'B2':[7,8,9],
                   'B3':[1,3,5],
                   'C':[5,3,6],
                   'D':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)
df1 = df.copy()

def a(df):
    cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('B')]
    df[cols] = df[cols].mul(df.A, axis = 0)
    return (df)


def b(df):
    df.loc[:, df.filter(regex=r'^B').columns] = df.loc[:, df.filter(regex=r'^B').columns].mul(df.A, axis=0)    
    return (df)

print (a(df))
print (b(df1))
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: (^u^). Have a good day, too! 
PS: In China, it's already night.

Answer (score 1):

you have almost done it:

```
In [136]: df.loc[:, df.filter(regex=r'^B').columns] = df.loc[:, df.filter(regex=r'^B').columns].mul(df.A, axis=0)

In [137]: df
Out[137]:
   A  B1  B2  B3  B4  F
0  1   4   7   1   5  7
1  2  10  16   6   6  4
2  3  18  27  15  18  3
```

Comment: Thanks for your wise advice!